# how can i adjust the height of a table with code Swift.2

Tags: ios, swift

I've made it so a textfield is always on top of the keyboard (like in the messages app, whatsapp...) but my problem is that this poses the table above it up too because everything is in a scrollview. How can i make it so the table resizes so it fits in the space between the keyboard and top of the screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ4cp.png)

Comment: My suggestion is to see https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController they've done excellent job.

Comment: Or use autolayout. Sounds like you are using framing instead.

Comment: i have used auto layout but because its in a scrollview it makes me have to give the table a height.. how can I make it so i can change the height constraint?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can resize your UITableView when you change the frame.

For example:

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,200);
```

To setup this, you should check when the keyboard is present. With:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:  Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);

     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
}


deinit {
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self);
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    yourTableView.frame = newFrame // use CGRectMake()
}
```

2. Why you want to "resize" your TableView? if its on an scrollView, it dont need to be resized. Just use **scrollRectToVisible** on your scrollView to show your textBox.

Read here more about usage of UIScrollView:

http://www.appcoda.com/uiscrollview-introduction/

Or by Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH1-SW1

Comment: Showing the textbox isn't the issue. When i get the textbox to show the top half of the table disappears. I want to resize the table so you can scroll through all the stuff in the table while the keyboard is up. please could you show me how i could do this? thanks

Comment: As i said, you are able to change the frame. You could check when the keyboard is present, and then change the frame of your TableView. Ill update my Answer.